# In Fortran IV, how are arrays assigned by a single value, and how are some goto operations handled?

Tags: arrays, fortran, variable-assignment, goto, ackermann

I have a semantic problem with a very old Fortran IV (Fortran 66) program. This leads to 2 questions.

**Context**

The program should calculate the Ackermann function in O(1) memory. It comes from here:
[The old paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/363744.363781?casa_token=RC2ijt8AkrMAAAAA:p8BY27w3yL3HUTB67qCvpOL7gUQ-QpFDdKx3yc7_IwuBE3O_tWK_J8wTb-rrszW6kq7slCsOUT5PgA).

It is a paper written by Henry Gordon Rice ([Gordon Rice](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Gordon_Rice), the wiki page stipulates that he wrote the above paper). Why reading such an old paper? For fun and as a reScience test.

This is the original code:

```
 1    INTEGER FUNCTION ACKER(M,N)
 C    Size of VALUE and PLACE tables is one more than LARGEST M EXPECTED (else too long computation)
 2      INTEGER VALUE(6), PLACE(6)
 C    Test ofr Zero M
 3      IF (M .NE. O) GO TO 6
 4      ACKER = N+l
 5      RETURN
 C   Non Zero M INITIALIZE FOR ITERATION
 6      VALUE = 1
 7      PLACE = 0
 C      ITERATION LOOP. GET NEW VALUE.
 8      VALUE = VALUE + 1
 9      PLACE = PLACE + 1
 10     DO 18 I=1,M
 11         IF (PLACE(I) .NE. 1) GO TO 16
 C          INITIATE NEW LEVEL
 12         VALUE(I+1) = VALUE
 13         PLACE(I+1) = 0
 14         IF (I .EQ. M) GO TO 18
 15         GO TO 8
 16         IF (PLACE(I) .NE. VALUE(I+1) GO TO 8
 17         VALUE(I+1) = VALUE
 18         PLACE(I+1)=PLACE(I+1)+1
 C     CHECK FOR END OF ITERATION
 19     IF (PLACE(M+1) .NE. N) GO TO 8
 20     ACKER = VALUE
 21     RETURN
 22  END
```

The code again without comments:

```
 1   INTEGER FUNCTION ACKER(M,N)
 2      INTEGER VALUE(6), PLACE(6)
 3      IF (M .NE. O) GO TO 6
 4      ACKER = N+l
 5      RETURN
 6      VALUE = 1
 7      PLACE = 0
 8      VALUE = VALUE + 1
 9      PLACE = PLACE + 1
 10     DO 18 I=1,M
 11         IF (PLACE(I) .NE. 1) GO TO 16
 12         VALUE(I+1) = VALUE
 13         PLACE(I+1) = 0
 14         IF (I .EQ. M) GO TO 18
 15         GO TO 8
 16         IF (PLACE(I) .NE. VALUE(I+1) GO TO 8
 17         VALUE(I+1) = VALUE
 18         PLACE(I+1)=PLACE(I+1)+1
 19     IF (PLACE(M+1) .NE. N) GO TO 8
 20     ACKER = VALUE
 21     RETURN
 22  END
```

It is a very short program compared to most iterative ones:

- [Roseta Ackermann function](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)
- [KoopLoop version](https://timkoop.com/koop_loop_ackermanns_function_as_a_for_loop), perhaps the second algorithm of the paper [Iterative Ackermann](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397588900461),
  which seems close to the original program of Gordon Rice.

**Problem**

So, when reading the code, to understand how it works, 2 things troubled me:

1. If PLACE is an array/table, how works the assignment PLACE=1 ? 1 everywhere ? 1 to the first cell ? PLACE is also a kind of hidden index ?
   It is the same question about PLACE = PLACE + 1. How it works ? (recall PLACE is not an integer variable but an array)
2. Some GOTOs inside the DO-LOOP (a kind of for-loop) go away from the range (body) of the do-loop. And then the code can re-enter the range/body of the the do-loop. If so, is the variable J reset? Or is a copy used (so there would be a hidden stack?).

Some references about the Fortran IV versions:
[Fortran IV
Programmer's
Reference Manual](http://www.bitsavers.org/www.computer.museum.uq.edu.au/pdf/DEC-10-AFDO-D%20decsystem10%20FORTRAN%20IV%20Programmer%27s%20Reference%20Manual.pdf)

I tried to convert the code to Java, but without an understanding of the semantics, I can't. I tried to compile it with "g77 -ff66" without success. And I tried reading papers about Fortran IV and iterative algorithms for the Ackermann function.

Hint: I am absolutely not a Fortran programer.

Comment: I never heard of reScience before, very nice!

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. What does "I tried to compile it with "g77 -ff66" without success." mean? Was there any error message?

Comment: By the way, note that this code is actually a valid Fortran 2008 code, thanks to the strong emphasis put on backward compatibility in the revisions of the standard. Any recent version of any popular compiler (e.g. gfortran) is able to compile it.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1)

Assigning or using a whole array at once is a so-called "array syntax", which was introduced only in Fortran 90. AFAIK, something like `PLACE = 0` was illegal in Fortran 66 or 77. So there are two hypothesis here:

- the code was relying on a non-standard and non-portable behavior of some compiler(s) at that times, such as `PLACE` was (maybe) a shortcut for `PLACE(1)`
- someone modified the original code to take advantage of the F90 array syntax

But the latter hypothesis is unlikely, because the code also contains things like `VALUE(I+1) = VALUE`, which the assignment of a whole array to a scalar element: this is illegal in all Fortran standards, old or recent.

Part 2)

Escaping from a do-loop with a goto statement was fine (and before Fortran 90 it was the only way). In your example, when entering again the do-loop, the `J` variable is simply reset to the initial value of the loop, and there's no new instance of this variable.

What is/was not authorized is jumping inside a do-loop with a goto statement that is outside the loop.

### Edit

Here is, I think, the right version of the code.

- I replaced all unindexed array references by references to the first element
- I fixed some wrong indentations (this is the old-school fixed-source format, where statements had to start at column 7)
- I added a missing parenthesis on the line labelled "11"
- I replaced the `GO TO 18` by `GO TO 19` on the line labelled "14"

```
 1      INTEGER FUNCTION ACKER(M,N)
 2      INTEGER VALUE(6), PLACE(6)
 3      IF (M .NE. O) GO TO 6
 4      ACKER = N+l
 5      RETURN
 6      VALUE(1) = 1
 7      PLACE(1) = 0
 8      VALUE(1) = VALUE(1) + 1
 9      PLACE(1) = PLACE(1) + 1
 10     DO 18 I=1,M
 11         IF (PLACE(I) .NE. 1) GO TO 16
 12         VALUE(I+1) = VALUE(1)
 13         PLACE(I+1) = 0
 14         IF (I .EQ. M) GO TO 19
 15         GO TO 8
 16         IF (PLACE(I) .NE. VALUE(I+1)) GO TO 8
 17         VALUE(I+1) = VALUE(1)
 18         PLACE(I+1)=PLACE(I+1)+1
 19     IF (PLACE(M+1) .NE. N) GO TO 8
 20     ACKER = VALUE(1)
 21     RETURN
 22     END
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try the shortcut PLACE(1). Agree that your second hypothesis is unlikely because I copied the code from a PDF which is a scan of the original article (1965...)

Comment: The paper says the code was run on a Univac1107. https://www.fourmilab.ch/fourmilog/archives/2017-12/001732.html has a link to the "UNIVAC 1107 FORTRAN Programmer's Guide" I suggest you take a look at that and see if you work out the non-standard stuff in the above. That said [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place for this.

Comment: I have had a quick look to that pogrammer's guide, but couldn't find how for instance  `PLACE = 0` should be interpreted...

Comment: Neither could I - but it was such a brief look. I have half a suspicion of a scanning error somewhere, but the code looks like the provided paper. Unfortunately I don't have a Univac to hand.

Comment: Thanks also Ian. I will try to read the UNIVAC guide. I wonder if the code of the paper itself has not been (badly) corrected from the Rice's original program. And if it proves impossible (or too complex) to reproduce the execution, I'll have carried out myself an unsuccessful reproducibility experiment ^^.

Comment: It looks like it works as expected after replacing all unindexed arrays by references to the first element. A few fixes were needed also (missing parenthesis, and some indentations)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/763jebof3

Comment: Actually it doesn't work as expected, I didn't test it correctly. Your transcription of the code has a big error: on line 14, the `GO TO` should send to line 19, not to line 18. After this correction now the results look ok: https://godbolt.org/z/5fhKs4688

Comment: @PierU I think it should not read "line18"  / "line 19" in your comment but "label 18" / "label 19" (although in this case they are the same when the comments are removed.

Comment: @albert you're right